# How to destruct instance in atexit()

Tags: c++

I want to **call destructor** of an instance (*proc*) always **before my program ends**, especially after *return 1* or *exit()* in *main*.

I found C++ function **atexit()**, but it requires pointer to void function with no argument, so the code below cannot be compiled. *How I can solve it, please?*

Destructor of my instance requires MySQL connection.

```
#include <WinSock.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>

// Declarations for Mysql DB

using namespace std;

class Process {
  public:
     ~Process();
};

Process::~Process ()
{
    // Interaction with DB
}

int main(void) 
{
  // Join to DB

  atexit(proc.~Process); // Call desctructor of instance proc before program ends

  Process proc;

  // App code

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There is a chance that what You are trying to doesn't really need you to do this at all.It is definitely not needed in the example you show because destructor of `proc` will be automatically called before main returns,but that seems to be just a demonstration example.

Comment: related? http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun96.txt  (the link refers to destroying a Singleton elegantly.  This has been the only time I have attempted something similar to what you are trying to do.)

Comment: see related http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`proc` has automatic duration, i.e. when exiting `main`, it will be destroyed automatically (and the destructor invoked) - you don't need the `atexit` business..

Unless as @Rob mentions below, you call `exit()` in your code somewhere... if that's the case, then you'll have to allocate `Process` on the heap, provide a function that `atexit` can call which is aware of this instance, and delete it there...

Comment: Unless he plans on calling `exit()` from the bowels of his program.

Answer (score 4):

Just make it a global `std::auto_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>`:

```
std::auto_ptr<Process> proc; // 1) initialized with NULL before main() is called

int main() {
    proc.reset(new Process); // 2) re-initialized
}

// 3) proc destructor is called after main() exits
```

Answer (score 3):

Use C++:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<Process> g_proc;

int main()
{
  g_proc.reset(new Process(some, runtime, params));

  // all done!
}
```

Objects of static storage duration (e.g. globals, like our `g_proc` here) are destroyed after `main` exits, and the destructor of `unique_ptr` will take care of the object destruction.

Alternatively you can make `g_proc` a `static` variable inside `main`, though that's a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Change your program logic slightly to allocate your `Process` object dynamically:

```
Process *pProc;

void killProc() {
  delete pProc;
}

int main(void) 
{
  // Join to DB

  atexit(killProc); // Call desctructor of instance proc before program ends

  pProc = new Process();
  Process& proc = *pProc;

  // App code

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *proc* is not a pointer, it will be automatically deleted at the end of the *main*() function, and it's destructor will be called (before the memory is deallocated).

The *atexit*() function is not a C++ function, but is part of the standard C library.

If you need to call the destructor BEFORE the end of the *main*() function, you need to allocate the *proc* variable as a pointer.

You can also avoid the usage of global variables plus C functions by using an application class this way:

```
class Application
{
 public:
 Application() { proc = new Process(); /* other init code */ }
 ~Application() { delete proc; /* other clean-up code */ }

 int run()
 {
  /* your application code goes here */
 }

 private:
 Process *proc;
}

int main()
{
 Application app;
 int result = app.run();
 /* Post clean-up code */
 return result;
}
```

If you plan using C++11 can also rely on the 'unique_ptr' template. Avoid using 'auto_ptr' since it is deprecated.

Comment: Funny you'd say "The atexit() function is not a C++ function, but is part of the standard C library." Implementation detail, but if you look into assembly output the constructors of global objects register their destructors with `atexit()`. See `-fuse-cxa-atexit` gcc option.

Comment: Does this make `atexit()` a C++ function? It is part of the C library, even if used in C++ code (same as the `exit()` function).

Comment: C++ standard requires `atexit()` in 18.3 Start and termination.